# Customizing chorus in songs package

Tags: formatting, xpatch, songs

I'm trying to customize the chorus of the `songs` package but I can't figure out why the first line isn't aligned properly. the *R* should be at the same position as the verse number *(1.)*.

I used `xpatch` to eliminate all occurrences of `\SB@cbarshift` and `\cbarwidth`. Then adjusted the chorus to be formatted the same way as verses.

[image: songs]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bookmarks,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[chorded,noshading]{songs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\songcolumns{1}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\justifyleft}
  {\SB@cbarshift}
  {\ifSB@inchorus\advance\leftskip\versenumwidth\fi}
  {}{}

\xpatchcmd{\justifycenter}
  {\SB@cbarshift}{}
  {}{}

\xpatchcmd{\SB@par}
  {\ifdim\cbarwidth>\z@\nobreak\else\SB@ilpenalty\fi}{}
  {}{}

\xpatchcmd{\brk}
  {
    \ifdim\cbarwidth=\z@%
    \ifrepchorus\marks\SB@cmarkclass{}\fi%
    \SB@breakpoint\brkpenalty%
  }
  {
    \endgroup\egroup
    \ifrepchorus\ifSB@gotchorus\else
      \global\setbox\SB@chorusbox\vbox{
        \unvbox\SB@chorusbox
        \SB@chorusbar\SB@box
        \unvcopy\SB@box
        \SB@breakpoint\brkpenalty
      }%
    \fi
  }
  {}{}

\xpatchcmd{\beginchorus}
  {\vnumberedfalse}{\vnumberedtrue}
  {}{}

\xpatchcmd{\SB@@beginchorus}
  {
    \setbox\SB@box\vbox\bgroup\begingroup%
      \ifchorded%
        \def\SB@everypar{%
          \vrule\@height\baselineskip\@width\z@\@depth\z@%
          \gdef\SB@everypar{}%
        }%
        \everypar{\SB@everypar\everypar{}}%
      \fi%
  }
  {
    \setbox\SB@box\vbox\bgroup\begingroup
      \ifvnumbered
        \def\SB@everypar{
          \setbox\SB@box\hbox{R}
           \ifdim\wd\SB@box<\versenumwidth
             \setbox\SB@box
             \hbox to\versenumwidth{\unhbox\SB@box\hfil}
           \fi
          \ifchorded\vrule\@height\baselineskip\@width\z@\@depth\z@\fi
          \placeversenum\SB@box
          \gdef\SB@everypar{}
        }
      \else
        \def\SB@everypar{
          \ifchorded\vrule\@height\baselineskip\@width\z@\@depth\z@\fi
          \gdef\SB@everypar{}
        }
      \fi
      \everypar{\SB@everypar\everypar{}}
  }
  {}{}

\xpatchcmd{\SB@endchorus}
  {\SB@chorusbar\SB@box}{}
  {}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{songs}{}

\beginsong{Dämmerung fällt}

\newchords{dfverse}
\newchords{dfchorus}

\beginverse\memorize[dfverse]
\[a]Dämmerung fällt und grauer \[d]Nebel zieht auf, \[G]einsamer Ruf von wilden \[C]Schwänen klingt auf.
\[a]Sitzen wir um das lodernd' \[d]Feuer herum, \[C]fragen uns leise: Warum \[G]zieh'n wir, warum?
\endverse

\beginchorus\memorize[dfchorus]
\[F]Nordwärts steh'n uns're Sterne, \[C]nordwärts, in weiter Ferne, \[a]nordwärts, da suchen wir das \[G]Glück.
\[F]Nordwärts bei Dunkelheiten, \[C]nordwärts durch Einsamkeiten, \[G]nordwärts, für uns gibt's kein Zu\[a]rück.
\endchorus

\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your particular situation, it is the case of the 4 missing `%` signs in your patch of `\SB@@beginchorus`.  Though to be honest, I would be adding even more `%` signs at the end of lines, to prevent stray spaces from getting introduced under other circumstances.

See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bookmarks,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[chorded,noshading]{songs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\songcolumns{1}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\justifyleft}
  {\SB@cbarshift}
  {\ifSB@inchorus\advance\leftskip\versenumwidth\fi}
  {}{}

\xpatchcmd{\justifycenter}
  {\SB@cbarshift}{}
  {}{}

\xpatchcmd{\SB@par}
  {\ifdim\cbarwidth>\z@\nobreak\else\SB@ilpenalty\fi}{}
  {}{}

\xpatchcmd{\brk}
  {
    \ifdim\cbarwidth=\z@%
    \ifrepchorus\marks\SB@cmarkclass{}\fi%
    \SB@breakpoint\brkpenalty%
  }
  {
    \endgroup\egroup
    \ifrepchorus\ifSB@gotchorus\else
      \global\setbox\SB@chorusbox\vbox{
        \unvbox\SB@chorusbox
        \SB@chorusbar\SB@box
        \unvcopy\SB@box
        \SB@breakpoint\brkpenalty
      }%
    \fi
  }
  {}{}

\xpatchcmd{\beginchorus}
  {\vnumberedfalse}{\vnumberedtrue}
  {}{}

\xpatchcmd{\SB@@beginchorus}
  {
    \setbox\SB@box\vbox\bgroup\begingroup%
      \ifchorded%
        \def\SB@everypar{%
          \vrule\@height\baselineskip\@width\z@\@depth\z@%
          \gdef\SB@everypar{}%
        }%
        \everypar{\SB@everypar\everypar{}}%
      \fi%
  }
  {
    \setbox\SB@box\vbox\bgroup\begingroup
      \ifvnumbered
        \def\SB@everypar{%
          \setbox\SB@box\hbox{R}%
           \ifdim\wd\SB@box<\versenumwidth
             \setbox\SB@box
             \hbox to\versenumwidth{\unhbox\SB@box\hfil}%
           \fi
          \ifchorded\vrule\@height\baselineskip\@width\z@\@depth\z@\fi
          \placeversenum\SB@box
          \gdef\SB@everypar{}%
        }
      \else
        \def\SB@everypar{
          \ifchorded\vrule\@height\baselineskip\@width\z@\@depth\z@\fi
          \gdef\SB@everypar{}
        }
      \fi
      \everypar{\SB@everypar\everypar{}}
  }
  {}{}

\xpatchcmd{\SB@endchorus}
  {\SB@chorusbar\SB@box}{}
  {}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{songs}{}

\beginsong{Dämmerung fällt}

\newchords{dfverse}
\newchords{dfchorus}

\beginverse\memorize[dfverse]
\[a]Dämmerung fällt und grauer \[d]Nebel zieht auf, \[G]einsamer Ruf von wilden \[C]Schwänen klingt auf.
\[a]Sitzen wir um das lodernd' \[d]Feuer herum, \[C]fragen uns leise: Warum \[G]zieh'n wir, warum?
\endverse

\beginchorus\memorize[dfchorus]
\[F]Nordwärts steh'n uns're Sterne, \[C]nordwärts, in weiter Ferne, \[a]nordwärts, da suchen wir das \[G]Glück.
\[F]Nordwärts bei Dunkelheiten, \[C]nordwärts durch Einsamkeiten, \[G]nordwärts, für uns gibt's kein Zu\[a]rück.
\endchorus

\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that leaving them can cause these issues.